# Maven integrating in Eclipse RAD impossible

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, rad

I'm using RAD and since the morning I'm trying to integrate Maven with Eclipse(RAD) by using that command:
Help -> Instal New Software, then putting this link:

http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/

then checked "Maven integration for Eclipse"

the errors occured below:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317     (      org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1376390079411            (SharedProfile_bootProfile 1.0.0.1376390079411)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
  Eclipse Jobs Mechanism 3.5.2.R36x_v20110419 (org.eclipse.core.jobs      3.5.2.R36x_v20110419)
  Eclipse Jobs Mechanism 3.5.300.v20130429-1813 (org.eclipse.core.jobs 3.5.300.v20130429-1813)
  Eclipse Jobs Mechanism 3.5.101.v20120113-1953 (org.eclipse.core.jobs 3.5.101.v20120113-1953)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1376390079411 (SharedProfile_bootProfile 1.0.0.1376390079411)
  To: org.eclipse.core.jobs [3.5.2.R36x_v20110419]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Equinox Provisioning Discovery 1.0.101.v20130327-2119 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery.compatibility 1.0.101.v20130327-2119)
   To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 1.0.0
   Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Equinox Provisioning ECF based Transport 1.1.0.v20130516-1858 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 1.1.0.v20130516-1858)
  To: bundle org.eclipse.core.jobs 3.5.100
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: m2e Marketplace 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.discovery 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
  To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery.compatibility 0.0.0
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
 From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
  To: org.eclipse.m2e.discovery [1.4.0.20130601-0317]
```

I have no idea what mentioned "Eclipse Jobs Mechanism...    " is I can't find its in the installed software.

Tried to use another repositories like:

http://bitstrings.github.com/m2e-connectors-p2/releases

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/0.15.0/N/0.15.0.201207090125/

They let me start the instalation but It's stop in +/- 40 %...

Anyone could help me install Maven in my IDE? 
Thank You in advance

Answer (score 3):

Did you use the maven installation instructions by IBM?

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/2fad2df2-9c68-4aa3-abba-01e910211998/page/5531e600-93c7-46f6-86f4-a570b1bcf391/attachment/9f11dc95-a9ae-4522-9ed1-2c8a7ca165cd/media/RAD_m2e-Nov(update%20Jun%202012).pdf

Comment: Taking a closer look at your problem, I'd say that "Only one of the following can be installed at once" suggests that you are trying to stall a wrong version Maven. And in this case of "Eclipse Jobs Mechanism". Eclipse is probably trying to install that mechanism of your current version and it collides with the Mechanism in your RAD Platform. From the plugins I'd suggest that you are using RAD 8?

Answer (score 1):

I have ceased installing m2e within RAD "myself" (in the sense of using an update site in Install New Software). Rather I use the option "Maven" via the IBM Installation Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason you are installing Maven using that update site link instead of installing it using Installation Manager? To install Maven using Installation Manager you just need to open IM and select the checkbox for Maven.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody still has to use this old version of RAD:

http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/ does not work - it points to the latest version of m2e which requires a newer base-eclipse.

Instead, add all of the following locations:

- http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.4/
- http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2e-extensions/m2eclipse-wtp/
- http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2e-extensions/m2e-mavenarchiver/